# Formatting text to be in exact center of page, and be the correct size.. [HTML / CSS]

Tags: html, css, web

I'm building myself website in a class that I am taking at my school. I had to design what I wanted my site to look like,  and now I have to build it.

I've found a stylesheet I really like, "Roboto Slab", and I have a background. I've got most of the main page done, actually.

I keep running into this one error when trying to format my text. I'm trying to make the text in the EXACT center of the web page, and it's a little lower than center. Not only that, but it gives the option to scroll left and right, and there is no reason that I can see for it to be doing that.

Here's the code for the site.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MySite</title>
    <meta name="description" content="My Site.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>html,body,.do-you-even-flexbox{
        height:100%;
        } body {
            margin:0;
            font:normal 14px/1.2 "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align:center;
            background:#111 url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Alpamayo.jpg/1280px-Alpamayo.jpg') center top/ cover;
            }::-moz-selection {
                background:#2fdd11;
                color:#fff;
            }::selection {
                background:#2fdd11;
                color:#fff;
            } a {
                text-decoration:none;
            }a:hover, a:active{
                outline:none;
                text-decoration:underline;
            }a:focus {
                outline:thin dotted;
            }.do-you-even-flexbox,.container {
                position:absolute;
                top:50%;
                width:100%;
                height:1em;
                margin-top: -.5em;
            }.container { 
                padding:8px 20px 15px;
            }h1, h2 {
                font-family:"Roboto Slab",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                margin:0;
                color:#000;
                font-weight:400;
                font-size:96px;
            }.social{
                margin-top:30px;
            }.social a {
                background-color:#F5F7FA;
                border-radius:35px;
                margin:0 3px;
                width:26px;
                height:26px;
                padding:16px;
                display:inline-block;
                -webkit-transition:background-color .6s ease;
                transition:background-color .6s ease;
            }.social a:hover,.social a:focus {
                outline:none;
                background-color:#FC6E51;
            }.icon{
                width:26px;
                height:26px;
            }.icon>path{
                fill:#111;
            }.links{
                color:#333;
                margin-top:30px;
            }.links a{
                display:inline-block;
                padding:0 5px;
                color:#000;
            }.links {
                color:#000;
            }.links a:hover{
                color:#000;
            } @media (max-width: 660px) {
                h1{
                    font-size:64px;
                }h2 {
                    font-size:24px;
                }
            } @media (max-width: 460px) {
                .do-you-even-flexbox {
                    display:none;
                }.container{
                    margin:0 auto;
                    margin-top:4%;
                }.links a{
                    display:block;
                }h1{
                    font-size:48px;
                }h2{
                    font-size:16px;
                }
            } @media (max-width: 350px) {
                h1{
                    font-size:40px;
                }
            }
    </style>;

</head>
<body>
    <i class="do-you-even-flexbox"></i>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hi.</h1>
        <h2>This is the website for my independent study.</h2>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="some_page_here">Example Page.</a>
            <a href="some_page_here">Another Page.</a>
            <a href="some_page_here">Another page! :D</a>
            <a href="derp">Blah blah</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong with this? I've tried using the align: center methods, but none of those have worked for me.

!! EDIT !!
Fixed font size issue. Yay me. Just created a new section in the CSS code for H2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a div for that center content, see html

```
<i class="do-you-even-flexbox"></i>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
         <h1>Hi.</h1>

         <h2>This is the website for my independent study.</h2>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="links"> <a href="some_page_here">Example Page.</a>
 <a href="some_page_here">Another Page.</a>
 <a href="some_page_here">Another page! :D</a>
 <a href="derp">Blah blah</a>

</div>
```

then you can center that div (I named it "box") with CSS using flex-box model

```
html, body, .do-you-even-flexbox {
    height:100%;
width:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    font:normal 14px/1.2"Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    background:#111 url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Alpamayo.jpg/1280px-Alpamayo.jpg') center top/ cover;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background:#2fdd11;
    color:#fff;
}
::selection {
    background:#2fdd11;
    color:#fff;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:focus {
    outline:thin dotted;
}
.do-you-even-flexbox, .container {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    padding:8px 20px 15px;
    display:flex;
    align-content:center;
}
.box {
    height:20%;
    margin:auto
}
h1, h2 {
    font-family:"Roboto Slab", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:24px;
}
.social {
    margin-top:30px;
}
.social a {
    background-color:#F5F7FA;
    border-radius:35px;
    margin:0 3px;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    padding:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:background-color .6s ease;
    transition:background-color .6s ease;
}
.social a:hover, .social a:focus {
    outline:none;
    background-color:#FC6E51;
}
.icon {
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
}
.icon>path {
    fill:#111;
}
.links {
    color:#333;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.links a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 5px;
    color:#000;
}
.links {
    color:#000;
}
.links a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
@media (max-width: 660px) {
    h1 {
        font-size:64px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size:24px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 460px) {
    .do-you-even-flexbox {
        display:none;
    }
    .container {
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:4%;
    }
    .links a {
        display:block;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size:48px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size:16px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 350px) {
    h1 {
        font-size:40px;
    }
}
```

I made your heading tags smalles so you can see the effect, but you will need to adjust that to your needs and also you may need to adjust box height, but you'll get the idea. [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/53mwmzqy/)

Answer (score 0):

`h1` and `h2` have the same size because your CSS file is included before the `<style>` tag, which defines `h1` and `h2` to have `font-size: 96px`. Just move the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css">
```

after `<style> ... </style>`.

Comment: Fixed it myself, see above post.

Thank you for posting this though, it 50% showed me what the issue was about the font size.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code in a fiddle. I took out a lot of your, already defined code, but you can simply add that back in there. I think this will give you a good start of what you want to accomplish.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5u785mbv/)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="centerText">
            <h1>Hi.</h1>
            <h1>This is the website for my independent study.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="#">Example Page.</a>
        <a href="#">Another Page.</a>
        <a href="#">Another page! :D</a>
        <a href="#">Blah blah</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Alpamayo.jpg/1280px-Alpamayo.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    height: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#centerText {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```